# Managing customer information in the cloud or on private server

Tags: gratis, crm

My girlfriend owns a cosmetic salon where she works as beautician. She writes customer information down into a notebook, but wants to automate this.

I recommended that she write all her customers information on Google Contacts. You can add custom fields for every contact, and has fuzzy search as well which makes looking for a customers name quite fast.

But my girlfriend does not really trust Google.

Is there any 3rd party software, or even better, a private solution to host on your own server, that offers a similar user experience, to manage and store customer information, preferably on the cloud to make the data ubiquitous?

She wants to store names, address information, contact information, and special remarks. All fields have to be searchable, fuzzy search would be great.

Comment: How about an Excel spreadsheet?

Comment: Excel Spreadsheet isn't in the cloud, and what is worse, searching through a document is hard.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are still looking for an app that would manage your customer information. I'd advise checking out Simitless. It is a platform that allows you to create an information system/data app focusing on what you need. It gives you the tools to design your app from readily available modules to track what you want and how you want it.

It is:

- not Google related (well, there is Google Analytics for anonymous stats in the background but you can use [Ghostery](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/ghostery/) to block it and be Google-free),
- always accessible online,
- you can have multiple people working on the app at the same time (if your business grows and you need to enable multiple people to get hold of your customers' information),
- you can track any and all information you want,
- you can import/export your data, etc.

But:

- no fuzzy search.

**Full disclosure: I am part of the startup that designed that platform.** We just launched recently, still in beta. If you want to try it out and need some help, I can definitely give you/your girlfriend a hand. Just get in touch. (If you want to quickly try it out, there is a template for a [Customer Information Management App](https://simitless.com/en/templates?or=st&preview=templates-mailing-contacts) that can fit what you described your girlfriend wanted to track. Here is a quick preview:

[image]

And, since it is just a template, she can take it as a basis and modify it to her heart's desire.) It might be just what you are looking for. And let me know how it goes, if you decide to give it a go.

Comment: 9 out of 10 answers are promoting your own platform. Please have a look at [How not to be a spammer](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/promotion); especially *Post good, relevant answers, and if some (**but not all**) happen to be about your product or website, that’s okay.*

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to be pushy. I honestly have been trying to give relevant answers to relevant and mostly unresolved questions. It is true that most of them link to my project, for now, but I do feel that among all the solutions that are available, ours answers the needs of askers best. I read this link before and I really thought I was following the guidelines, providing full disclosure and custom solutions for each question. Thanks for bringing it to my attention though. I'll try to tip the balance towards other solutions as well to better develop this community.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking at [www.youreontime.com](http://www.youreontime.com). I built it, but it does exactly what you want. It includes a complete CRM with the ability to SMS or Email clients reminders and marketing, an appointment scheduler that also works on your phone and a Sales screen to check out at the end of the service.